# Ansible AWX/Tower - Access a variable saved as artifact from another play

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I have a playbook which contains more than one plays. One of the plays generates a variable and stores it using the set_stats module as an artifact. The subsequent plays need to access the variable, but an error occurs that the given variable is undefined. How can I access a variable in the artifacts? (Btw using a workflow which would result in saving the variable in the extra_variables instead of the artifacts container is no option in this scenario)

**The Problem in detail:**

I have the following playbook which includes 2 plays which get executed on different hosts:

```
---
- hosts: ansible
  roles:
    - role_parse_strings

- hosts: all, !ansible
  roles:
    - role_setup_basics
    - role_create_accounts
```

The role "role_parse_strings" in the first play generates the variable "users" which gets stored because of the **set_stats** module as an artifact. The following content lands in the artifact section of ansible awx:

```
users:
  - username: user1
    admin: true
  - username: user2
    admin: false
```

When the role "role_create_accounts" gets executed which tries to access the variable "users" in the following way...

```
- user: name={{ item.username }}
    shell=/bin/bash
    createhome=yes
    groups=user
    state=present
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

..this error gets displayed:

```
{
    "msg": "'users' is undefined",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Comment: [`set_stat`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_stats_module.html) sets custom stats for the current ansible run that will be displayed at the end of the run if you configured the correct vars in ansible.cfg. It does not set variables. You should use [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) for this. You can get facts set on a particular host from any other host with `hostvars['machine_name'].name_of_var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set_fact to share variable between hosts. Below example show how to share a file content via set_fact.

```
- hosts: host1
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Slurp the public key
      slurp:
        src: /tmp/ssh_key.pub
      register: my_key_pub

    - name: Save the public key
      set_fact:
        my_slave_key: >-
          {{ my_key_pub['content'] | b64decode }} 

- hosts: host2
  vars:
    slave_key: "{{ my_slave_key }}"
  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_slave_key: >-
          {{ hostvars[groups["host1"][0]].my_slave_key | trim }}
```

We saved the content of public key as a fact name called my_slave_key and 
assgined it another variable as slave_key in host2 with:

```
hostvars[groups["host1"][0]].my_slave_key
```

Comment: This will work only if `host1` is a group name (which I seriously doubt) and the relevant host is the first one in the list. The correct naming in this case is more probably `hostvars['host1'].my_slave_key`.